# Recursive call resulting in nonetype return

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
import sys

memo={}
size_memo={}

def DP(arr,n):

    global memo
    global size_memo

    if(n==0):
        memo[n]=0
        size_memo[n]=1
        return memo[n], size_memo[n] 

    if(n in memo.keys()):
        return memo[n], size_memo[n]
    else:

        if(n-1 in memo.keys()):
            last=memo[n-1]
            last_size=size_memo[n-1]
        else:
            last, last_size= DP(arr, n-1)

        if(arr[n]>arr[last]):
            # we will obviously include n in the lis
            new_size=last_size+1
            memo[n]=n 
            size_memo[n]=new_size

        else:

            #forcefully including n and creating new longest_ss ending with n  and comparing with what last longest_seq
            i=n
            size_inc=1
            while(arr[i]>arr[i-1]):
                size_inc+=1
                i-=1    

            if(size_inc>size_exc):
                size_memo[n]=size_inc
                memo[n]=n

                return memo[n], size_memo[n]
            else:
                size_memo=size_exc
                memo[n]=last

                return memo[n], size_memo[n]

arr=[10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80]

l=len(arr)-1

print(DP(arr,l))
```

Error at line : **last, last_size= DP(arr, n-1)**

Error message: **cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object**

I can not understand why the recursive call is giving this error. please can anyone help?

I am trying to write a DP to calcualte longest increasing subsequence in an array, but the recursiion is giving this error.

Comment: it looks like in the line with the error, at some point, the recursive call succeeds but does not return 2 values. Consequently, at least one of the variables is assigned to None.
I would try adding a print statement directly after, to see if last and last_size hold values that make sense

Comment: Oh!1 figured it out, I have not returned any values after the if(arr[n]>arr[last]): statement. and yes its working fine now! :)